# J2OBJC Xcode Build Rule with external java source

Tags: java, xcode, external, j2objc

i'm using J2OBJC Xcode Build Rule Method to compile the the java source code to objective-C.

https://github.com/google/j2objc/wiki/Xcode-Build-Rules

However each time when there is changes in java source, i will have to manual copy it over to the Xcode project using drag and drop.

Is that any others way where i can compile from external java source without manual copy them.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you add new Java files, then you need to update the Xcode project. Changes in existing java files should be automatically translated and compiled in to your app. I've got that behaviour successfully using the Xcode-Build-Rules instructions.

Comment: How do you customise where the Output Files get generated? They seem to be generated automatically in the OS Simulator or some folder like that. Can you show me your OutputFiles Rules? Thanks.